Tag for Linguistic Relativity
This question prompted this (meta) question.
I added the tag "linguistic-relativity"
But it could be called a number of other things

Sapir-Whorf
Whorfianism
Linguistic Determinism
Linguistic perspectivism
Linguistic hermeneutics
Linguistic framing
Linguistic incommensurability

Are there any preferences out of these?
